# Are all zombies created equal?

Tags: terraria

So I like the new zombie models that Terraria 1.2 introduced.  They add a wonderful variety to an otherwise very normal mob.

But I've noticed a few...differences in each individual zombie.

Zombies that have a chest full of arrows seem to always drop wooden arrows for me. Small zombies seem particularly agile.  And the zombies with 'nice hair' seem a bit weaker than the rest of the zombies.

I've noticed skeletons having different models as well, and even that skeletons with mining hats emit light!

Are these different types of the same mob given different attributes?  Are some intrinsically 'tougher' or 'stronger' than others?  And if so, what ARE the differences between them?

Comment: The mining hats that emit light are not new. Don't forget about the zombies with a slime on their head, they drop gel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The different zombies are indeed different, as you yourself know. You can read about what makes them different on the official wiki's [Zombie](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Zombie) page.